# Datatable not working while changing the table Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

Datatable not working while changing the Id.
here is the code:

```
 $('#TableId1').DataTable(
                                {

                                    'columnDefs': [{
                                        'targets': 0,
                                        'searchable': false,
                                        'orderable': false,
                                        "bLengthChange": false, "pageLength": 15, "stateSave": true,
                                        'width': '1%',
                                        'className': 'dt-body-center',
                                    }
                                    ,


                                    ],
                                    "language":
                                        {
                                            "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
                                        },
                                    "processing": true,
                                    "serverSide": true,
                                    "order": [[0, "asc"]],
                                    "ajax":
                                        {
                                            "url": "/TicketTemplate/GetAssignData",
                                            "type": "POST",
                                            "dataType": "JSON"
                                        },
                                    "columns": [
                                                { "data": "Title" },
                                                { "data": "Description" },
                                                { "data": "Duedate" },
                                                { "data": "AssignBy" },
                                                { "data": "Status" }
                                    ]

                                });

                                //$("#note1").html("");
                                //$("#partialSummaryDiv").html("");
                                //$("#partialSummaryDiv").html(data.responseText);


                                //document.getElementsByClassName('braja')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
```

If i use instead of TableId It is working..what should i do??

Here is the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="TableId1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        @*<th>
            <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" id="chkall" data-set="#sample_1 .checkboxes" onclick="Selectallcheckbox()" />
                <span></span>
            </label>
        </th>*@
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> Description </th>
        <th> Duedate </th>
        <th> AssignBy</th>
        <th> Status </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

what should i do??

Why this is not hit the controller method can any one elaborate??
Where is the error??

Why is it not working??

Answer (score 0):

hi looks like everthing is fine 
if it is the first time u change the id plas check wheter it is updated or not by seeing your page source by pressing Ctrl + U.
if not update refresh your browser several time check then if it is updated or not if not clear all cookies and restart the browser

Note:and check whether all the jscript files loded or not in browser console

hope it may help u

Comment: I AM NOT GETTING

Comment: In first case i am using first table ..for first table the id is TableId and for 2nd table which is on the different partial value having TableId 1  but for tableid1 it is not working

Comment: what should i do